# loop error - Runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel

I have a loop that returns a runtime error 13 and I'm not sure why. I have changed the whole column to text and it still does not work - anyone have any idea why? There is the string "Test" in myColumn. The line that returns the error is the one beginning If Left(

```
Option Explicit

Sub myMacro()

Dim startPoint As range
Dim myCell As range
Dim columnToFind As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim myColumn As range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("mySheet").Activate

Dim myDate As String                            

myDate = Application.InputBox("Please enter the date you would like to run 
the macro for (DD/MM/YY)")



Rows("4:4").Select
Selection.Find(What:=myDate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas _
    , LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

Set startPoint= ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)

ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 2).Insert

columnToFind = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(myDate, Rows("4:4"), 0) - 
1


i = startPoint.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

Set myColumn = startPoint.Offset(0, (-i) + 1).EntireColumn


For Each myCell In myColumn

    If Left(myCell.Value, 4) = "Test" Then

        myCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "testing"

    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the error? How is myColumn declared? Can you write `Dim myColumn as Range` on the top and check how it works?

Comment: in which line do you get the error? And please add your variable declares. I recommend to use `Option Explicit`. Also what is `i` and `Yesterday`?

Comment: and are you certain that `myCell.Value` has enough characters to take the leftmost 4? because if its content consists of lets say, 2 characters, and you are trying to take the left 4, well.

Comment: @Banana that won't throw an error but just the left 2 characters. Not an issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ wrong, this is exactly the error that will be thrown in that case.

Comment: @Banana well `Dim a As String: a = "aa": Debug.Print Left(a, 4)` does not throw an error for me.

Comment: Edited - Line beginning 'If Left(' in the loop is the line that erorrs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `myCell` is looping through columns, because it is declared with `.EntireColumn`. Thus, if you write `Debug.Print myCell.Address`, it will display the whole column - e.g. `G:G`. And the whole column does not have `.Value`, thus it returns an error.

Try to loop like this: `For Each myCell in myColumn.Cells`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myColumn As Range
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim i As Long: i = 5
    Dim yesterday As Range: Set yesterday = Range("K10")

    Set myColumn = yesterday.Offset(0, (-i) + 1).EntireColumn
    For Each myCell In myColumn.Cells
        If Left(myCell.Value2, 4) = "Test" Then
            myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "testing"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes a lot of sense because the code worked when I did not use .EntireColumn